# Java Socket reading more data than anticipated

Tags: java, sockets, web, serversocket

I am having an issue with socket read where its trying to read more than 20 MB of data from socket but the data supposed to be read from socket is byte array of 4. I am pretty new to the `Socket` programming world so am not really what exactly going wrong with my socket read method

Below is my `open` method for Socket connection

```
public void open(String catalogName, String sshHost, String port) {
    String responseCode;
    try {               
        socket = new Socket(sshHost, port); // java.net.Socket
        socket.setSoTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000); // defaulting socket timeout to 3 minutes for now

        input = socket.getInputStream();
        output = socket.getOutputStream();            

        String command = String.format("new|Provider=SQLOLEDB;;;Initial Catalog=%s;", catalogName);
        logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Executing Command: " + command);
        output.write(getLittleEndianLength(command.length()));
        output.write(command.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        responseCode = getResponse();
        if (!responseCode.equals(ERROR_RESPONSE_CODE)) {
            throw new BaseApplicationException("Invalid response code when connecting to database:" + responseCode);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new BaseApplicationException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ee) {}
        throw new BaseApplicationException(e.getMessage());
    }           
}
```

Once the socket connection is open am trying to read the data in buffers using byte array of size of 4 as below and the data read from socket can not be more than `MAX_RX_LENGTH` which is 20 MB

```
public String read() {
    // read in the integer that defines the length of the result
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    int retval = 0;

    try {
        retval = read(b);
        if (retval == -1) return null;

        // convert the integer from Big Endian (used by C#) to little endian (java default)
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        int numberBytes = buffer.getInt();
        if (numberBytes > MAX_RX_LENGTH) // MAX_RX_LENGTH = 20971520 which is 20 MB
            throw new BaseApplicationException("Bytes to read was larger than max allowed. numberBytes="
                    + numberBytes);
        logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "reading " + numberBytes + " bytes");

        if (numberBytes > 0) {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[numberBytes];
            int total = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            // may not be able to read the full message in one try so need to loop
            while (total < numberBytes && (bytesRead = read(bytes, total, numberBytes - total)) >= 0) {
                logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "bytes read:" + bytesRead);
                total += bytesRead;
            }

            return new String(bytes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ee) {}
        throw new BaseApplicationException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}

public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    return input.read(b);
}

public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    return input.read(b, off, len);
}
```

In our production environment we keep seeing exception messages like `Bytes to read was larger than max allowed. numberBytes=543584032` even though socket read method supposed to read only byte array of size 4. We dont see this issue in pre-prod environments. Can someone help me how do I make sure the data read from socket is less than 20 MB?

Comment: Why would you expect any connection between the result of `buffer.getInt()` and the number of bytes you read?!

Answer (score 0):

You've interpreted the string " of " as a number and, of course, gotten nonsense. The bug is in code not shown causing synchronization to be lost between the sender and the recipient. When the sender sends some part of a string, the recipient is expecting the size of a block, and so gets garbage.